# Installing salt minion in ubuntu 20 for Windows(Windows terminal)

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having Ubuntu 20 LTS on Windows10(as a Windows subsystem for Linux).
While installing `salt minion` in the Ubuntu, I ran into issues. Later, I checked that `SaltStack` doesnt even have [listing](https://repo.saltstack.com/#ubuntu) on their website for Ubuntu20. Is that the reason I am not able to install? Or am I the only one facing the issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please can anyone add relevant tags like `ubuntu20` or `Windows-terminal(Preview)`? I am not having enough reputation to add.

Comment: You will need to ask them and not us about this. Generally speaking software running on 18.04 can run on 20.04 unless there is a major update of a specific element for that software (like when python went from v2 to v3 but that should not be an issue here as their software is up to date for v3.).

Comment: @Rinzwind My apologies! If this is absolutely no place to ask for help regarding Ubuntu on Windows, then I am ready to delete my question.

Comment: No no. That is fine. It is just that you ask about 3rd party software SaltStack and if their software supports 20.04. Seems a bit difficult for us to answer unless someone here uses this too. Unlikely so I only suggested it might be worth it to ask them :) It is TOTALLY acceptable for you to mail them and then add the reply to this question, marking it as solved ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 uses Python 3.8, which is not compatible with Salt v3000 and older: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/55310